# libasan giving stack-buffer-overflow inside time_t time (time_t *__timer) -> sys/time.h

Tags: c++, debugging, stack-overflow, address-sanitizer

I am facing a problem while using libasan to improve some code I have written.

**Situation**:

-- compile code with -fsanitize=address -lasan

-- run the code.

**Sample below**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>
using namespace std;
int main () {
    time_t currentTime ;
    time(&currentTime);
    std::cout << "current time ---> " << currentTime << endl;
}
```

**problem**: this code runs fine in the sample program, but fails in my application. the application crashes with the error stack trace:

```
==23316==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address ... at pc ... bp ... sp ... 
Address ... is located in stack of thread T3==23316==AddressSanitizer CHECK failed: ../../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_thread.cc:243 "((ptr[0] == kCurrentStackFrameMagic)) != (0)" (0x0, 0x0)
#0 0xf7261fe6  (/usr/lib32/libasan.so.3+0xc7fe6)
#1 0xf72682f9 in __sanitizer::CheckFailed(char const*, int, char const*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) (/usr/lib32/libasan.so.3+0xce2f9)
#2 0xf7266015  (/usr/lib32/libasan.so.3+0xcc015)
#3 0xf725d473  (/usr/lib32/libasan.so.3+0xc3473)
#4 0xf725dcc1  (/usr/lib32/libasan.so.3+0xc3cc1)
#5 0xf72612f6  (/usr/lib32/libasan.so.3+0xc72f6)
#6 0xf71d20a0 in __interceptor_time (/usr/lib32/libasan.so.3+0x380a0)
```

Now, I understand that this is not because of the code I posted above, but what I dont understand at present is how to find the location where I am messing up my stack pointer..

Any help is appretiated.

Comment: Look for UB in your code, especially when accessing pointers to local variables.

Comment: Compile with debug symbols? ASAN should tell you about who allocated the memory in question.

Comment: Yo, compiled with -g -o0. Asan just tells the line number pointing to "time(&currentTime);", "prints WRITE of size 4 at .... thread T3". If I remove this line with time, the problem goes to some other location.. But, if I run without ASAN, there is no crash/no error in processing, even when running for a day under load, I assume its a small problem, but where?

Comment: This could be a false positive, please take a look [here](https://github.com/CESNET/libyang/issues/203#issuecomment-262531899).